# Rails 4: Target items through a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, associations

I am fairly new to Rails and I have created the `FavoriteUser` model to allow users to favorite other users. That works fine. I'm showing the Favorited users of the current user on the `Tool` (another model) `Index` view.

Now I also want to show the Tools created by the Favorited User on that page, but I have no idea how to accomplish that.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tools
  has_many :favorite_users # just the 'relationships'
  # Favorite users of user
  has_many :favorite_relationships, class_name: "FavoriteUser", foreign_key: "c_user_id"
  has_many :userfavorites, through: :favorite_relationships, source: :user

  # Favorited by a user
  has_many :favorited_relationships, class_name: "FavoriteUser", foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :userfavorited_by, through: :favorited_relationships, source: :c_user
end

class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class FavoriteUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :c_user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "User"
end

class ToolsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @favorites = current_user.favorites.order("created_at DESC")
    @userfavorites = current_user.userfavorites.order("created_at DESC")
    # adding '@userfavoritestools' or similar
    @tools = Tool.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
    @user = current_user
  end
end

# app/views/tools/index.html.haml    
%h2 My Favorite Tools
- @favorites.each do |tool|
  = image_tag tool.cover_filename.url
  %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
  %p= tool.subtitle
  %p= tool.tag_list
  %p= tool.impressionist_count
  %p= link_to tool.get_upvotes.size, like_tool_path(tool), method: :get
  %p= link_to "Favorite", favorite_tool_path(tool, type: "favorite"), method: :get
  %p= link_to "Unfavorite", favorite_tool_path(tool, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
  %p= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(tool)
  %p= link_to 'http://ocubit.com/tools/'+tool.id.to_s
  %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)

%h2 My Favorite Users
- @userfavorites.each do |user|
  = image_tag gravatar_for user if user.use_gravatar == true
  = image_tag user.avatar_filename.url if user.use_gravatar == false
  %h2= link_to user.username, user
  %p= link_to "Favorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "favorite"), method: :get
  %p= link_to "Unfavorite", userfavorite_user_path(user, type: "unfavorite"), method: :get
  %p= user.tag_list
```

## Adding a loop for the Newset Tools published by favorite users!

```
%h2 My Tools
- @tools.each do |tool|
  = image_tag tool.cover_filename.url
  %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
  %p= tool.subtitle
  %p= tool.tag_list
  %p= tool.impressionist_count
  %p= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(tool)
  %p= link_to 'http://ocubit.com/tools/'+tool.id.to_s
  %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you evidently know how to use associations already ... can you show your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get the `@tools` of the `current_user, try the following:

```
def index
  @favorites = current_user.favorites.order("created_at DESC")
  @userfavorites = current_user.userfavorites.order("created_at DESC")
  @tools = current_user.tools.order("created_at DESC")
  @user = current_user
end
```

If you instead are looking to get the `@tools` of the `users` that are of `current_user`'s favorited `users`, then try the following:

```
def index
  @favorites = current_user.favorites.order("created_at DESC")
  @userfavorites = current_user.userfavorites.order("created_at DESC")
  @tools = Tool.where(user_id: @userfavorites.collect(&:id)).order("created_at DESC")
  @user = current_user
end
```

Or, you could move this logic into the `User` model and user that method, as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def tools_of_favorited_users
    Tool.where(user_id: userfavorites.collect(&:id))  
  end
end

def index
  @favorites = current_user.favorites.order("created_at DESC")
  @userfavorites = current_user.userfavorites.order("created_at DESC")
  @tools = current_user.tools_of_favorited_users.order("created_at DESC")
  @user = current_user
end
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. The tool loop is working fine. I just want to add a loop (edited the code @IndexView so you can see where) which contains all the newest tools published by all your favorited users.

Comment: Updated the answer.